Magento 2 coupon code shows 1 Times used in admin but it is not showing in any orders
We are currently using Magento version 2.4.5-p1. We've encountered an issue with the Magento cart price rule with coupon codes.
The problem is as follows:
1 - In the Magento admin panel -> Cart Price Rules, the coupon code appears as marked.(Times used 1)

2 - The coupon code is not showing in any orders or even does not appear in the admin coupon reports.
This issue occurs approximately 1 out of every 50 times.
Has anyone experienced this issue before, or does anyone know how to resolve it?
